# Difference in integer size for 64-bit system(confuse with my old 32-bit pc system)

Tags: windows, 64-bit, int, abi

Few months ago i get myself a laptop with cpu intel i7-2630qm with a 64-bit windows. While practising my programming skils under this system , I encountered some difference in terms of integer size which makes me think that it's probably due to my new 64-bit system.

Let's take a look at a code.

**The C Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 20;

    printf("%d %lld\n" , num , num);

    return 0;
}
```

**The Question :**

1.) I remember before getting this new laptop , which mean that time i'm still using my old 32-bit system , when i run this code , the program will print the integer `20` while some random number next to it due to the `%lld` specifier.

2.)But this phenomena no longer happen when i'm using my new laptop , it will instead print both integer correctly , even if i change the variable `num` to type `short`.

3.)Is it on a 64-bit system , there's new integer promotion which will promote `int` to long long when it's use as an argument??Or is it `short` integer can be promoted to `long long` which is 64-bit too when pass as an argument??

4.)Besides that I'm quite confuse with one thing , on 16-bit system , `int` would be 16-bit and it would be 32-bit when it's on a 32-bit system.But why isn't it become 64-bit when it's on a 64-bit??

==================================================================================
**Addon :**

1.)I choose "console program(64-bit)" as my project on the IDE while using my new laptop but "console program" on my 32-bit old PC system.

2.)I've check the size of `int` under "console program(64-bit)" project using `sizeof` operator and it returns 32-bit while `short` still remain 16-bit.The only change is `long` type , it's 64-bit and `long long` still remain its usual 64-bit size.

Comment: You are simply observing undefined behavior(using %lld as the printf specifier, but giving it an int or short instead of a long long), not some well defined integer promotion rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this side-effect because the calling convention is different for x64 code.  The function arguments in 32-bit x86 code are passed on the stack.  The printf() function will read a word from the stack that isn't part of the activation frame.  The odds that it contains a value of 0 are extremely low.

In x64 code, the first 4 arguments for a function are passed through cpu registers, not the stack.  The odds that the high word of the 64-bit register is zero by chance are quite good.  Left there by a previous 64-bit operation that worked with small numbers.  But certainly not guaranteed.

Trying to reason out the defined behavior of undefined behavior is otherwise not useful.  Other than trying to guess how the language is implemented for the core that's in your machine.  There are better resources for that.  Learning the machine code that's applicable to your compiler is an excellent shortcut.  Together with the decent debugger that shows you how your C code got translated into machine code.  Machine code has no undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand.  Check this for background info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 1):

Everything you are describing is specific to whatever spec your compiler is using and the platform you are on (with the exception that `long` is guaranteed to be at least the same size as `int`):

Wikipedia entries:

[long long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer)

[int](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)

The c99 standard seeks to end this ambiguity by adding specific types; `int32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc. There's also a POSIX spec that defines `u_int32_t`, etc.

**Edit:** I missed the question about `printf()`, sorry. As @nos points out in the comments on your question, passing something other than a `long long` to `%lld` results in *undefined behavior*. This means there is no rhyme or reason as to what it will do; unicorns spontaneously appearing would not be out of the question.

Oh - and on every compiler and OS I know, `int` is 32 bit. Changing that has the potential to break things that depend on it being 32 bit.

Comment: I've been using the same C compiler (Pelles C) all the time , even on my old 32-bit system.

Comment: Oh ya I notice something too , in my new 64-bit supported laptop , I choose "windows console(64-bit)" project but i choose "windows console" project in my old 32-bit system since the "windows console(64-bit)" does not exist.

Comment: ty :) I didn't think I'd said anything way off

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to an windows 64-bit compiler right now, but my guess is the following.

Your question is not about integer promotion, but regarding how parameters are passed from the function caller to the called function. This is beyond the C specification, but it is interesting to know.

In 32-bit, all parameters are divided into 32-bit blocks as all registers can hold 32 bits. So in this case we have the following stack layout:

```
[ 32-bit format string pointer ][ num as 32-bit ][ num as 32-bit ] junk...
```

In 64-bit, all parameters are divided into 64-bit blocks as all registers can hold 64 bits. So the stack will contain the following:

```
[ 64-bit format string pointer ][ num as 64-bit ][ num as 64-bit ] junk...
```

The upper 32 bits of the 64-bit registers holding 32-bit values are conveniently set to zero.

So when `printf` is reading a 64-bit number, it will load the equivalent of two 32-bit registers on a 32-bit platform but only one 64-bit register, with high bits cleared, on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: still trying to digest what you said :(

Comment: Is there something I can add?

Answer (score 1):

(1 and 2) As already stated, the behaviour in this situation is undefined, so the compiler is allowed to behave differently for any reason or indeed no reason at all.

(3) The compiler is allowed to define int as 64-bit, in which case no promotion would be necessary because all the variables in question would be the same size.  But it almost certainly doesn't.

(4) On most or all 64-bit compilers, int is 32-bits.  This is because int has been 32 bits for so long that programmers have come to expect it and changing it would break existing code.  As far as I know this isn't officially part of the standard, but it's one of those de-facto standards that are even harder to change. :-)